# How to set the rowStyleClass dependent on data I view?

Tags: xpages

Is it possible to add a rowStyleClass to a view dependent upon values in row columns?
At the moment I need to have my code on each column and I'd like to be able to set it on "globally"...
I have tried using viewEntry or assigning the "var" to rowData but without luck. The error's saying that viewEntry or rowData is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine for me (and adds the UNID of the document as styleClass):

```
<xp:viewPanel rows="5" id="viewPanel1" var="rowEntry"
    rowClasses="#{javascript:rowEntry.getDocument().getUniversalID()}">
```